# Can I change a Python bound method object's __str__() attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, instance, overriding

I would like to change the `__str__()` attribute of one of my class's **methods**.

(Note: Not to be confused with "trying to change the method `__str__()`".)

I have a class, MyClass, which has a method 'some_method'.  I can change the way MyClass displays itself by:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self): pass
    def some_method(self): pass
    def __str__(self): return "I'm an instance of MyClass!"
```

When I instantiate and print MyClass:

```
print(my_class)
```

I get:

`I'm an instance of MyClass!`

When I

```
print(my_class.some_method)
```

I get:

`<bound method my_class.some_method of <gumble margle object at mumble-jumble>>`

I would like to see instead:

`some_method in the instance my_class you Dope!`

I've tried overriding the **str** method of `some_method`:

```
def some_method(self):
    def __str__(self):
        return "You dope!"
```

But no love.

Attempting to brute-force it in IPython proved no better:

```
my_class.some_method.__str__ = lambda: "You Dope!"
```

gave

`AttributeError: 'method' object attribute '__str__' is read-only`

Is there an easy way to do this programmatically (preferrably in Python 3)?

Comment: Dumb question: do python methods even have attributes?  I for one wasn't aware that a python method is an object ... is it?

Comment: @GreenAsJade: everything's an object. That doesn't mean the language makes it *easy* set set attributes, though.

Comment: @GreenAsJade As they say, everything is an object. Yes, a bound method is an obect and [has attributes](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#methods).

Comment: As for the question, I don't think you can set attributes on bound method objects. You can, however, wrap the function in a descriptor that constructs a custom bound-method-like object (with any methods you want) in place of the built-in bound method type.

Comment: @delnan: So.... you're saying, "No, not easily"?  :-)

Comment: Any particular reason you're doing this? It sounds like a fun way to explore the language, but I'm not sure what use it would be in a program.

Comment: I'm creating an infrastructure for a testing library.  Users will create methods for various hardware model classes.  They will create lists of these method objects and pass them to an executor.  I want to be able to clearly display these lists of method objects.  I absolutely I need to keep these as simple as possible, as my users are not Python gods (yet, anyway).

Comment: If you want `print [x.some_method, x.another_method]` to work right, you'll need to override `__repr__` instead. In that case, I recommend keeping the `<>` around the string.

Comment: @user2357112: I'm ok with overriding `__repr__`.  I just have to keep this as simple as possible or I get grief from two groups: the test writers if it's hard to implement AND the test runners for noise in the test output.

Comment: @JS. For clean syntax, [use an annotation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21345198/703382) :)

Comment: @user2357112 I had this idea, overriding the ``__repr__`` method (since there is no ``__str__`` method in the type of a function) or to create a `__str__` method for the method. But I didn't succeed because overriding a method means subclassing the type of the object we want to make with an enhanced behaviour. And at this point there is no available type creating functions that can be used as a base class for a subclasing. How do you plan to do what you evoke ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to use a custom class instead of a class function:

```
class CustomFunction(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __call__(func, self):
        # This is the actual function
        pass

    def __get__(func, instance=None, type_=None):
        class CustomMethod(object):
            def __init__(self, instance, type_):
                self.im_self = instance
                self.im_class = type_
            def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
                return func(self.im_self, *args, **kw)
            def __str__(self):
                return '{} in the instance {} you Dope!'.format(func.name, self.im_self)

        return CustomMethod(instance, type_)
```

then use this in your class:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self): pass

    some_method = CustomFunction('some_method')
```

Demo:

```
>>> print MyClass().some_method
some_method in the instance <__main__.MyClass instance at 0x106b5ccb0> you Dope!
```

This works because functions are [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html); they return methods when their `__get__` method is called.

Comment: In this case, is "some_method" a class variable of MyClass?

Comment: @GreenAsJade: all regular methods are class attributes too; I just produced a custom one.

Comment: This implementation is weird. It took me quite a while to understand what you were doing with the `func` and `self` arguments. I'd find a decorator-based implementation much clearer.

Comment: @Martijn It seems to me it isn't the 1st time I see you writing that _"functions are descriptors"_. But I don't feel this to be correct. It is true that if `foo` is a function, `hasattr(foo.__class__,'__get__')` is True. However, this doesn't make of ``foo`` a descriptor because: 1/ a descriptor is an instance of a descriptor-defining class, 2/ this instance must be defined as an attribute in an owner class. Said shortly, a descriptor is an object that can be accessed through a dot notation. So free functions outside any class rigourously aren't descriptors. Do you see things like that or not?

Comment: No, a descriptor is anything that implements the [descriptor protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors).  Did you read the [descriptor howto](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) yet?  Functions are descriptors because the have a `.__get__()` method.

Comment: The protocol isn't *invoked* unless you use attribute access, but that doesn't make functions any less descriptors.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `@toStr("This is %s You Dope! :P")` above the method.

```
class MyClass():
    @toStr("This is %s You Dope! :P")
    def some_method(self):
        print("method is doing something... Here is an attrbute... "+str(self.kk))
    def __str__(self): return "I'm an instance of MyClass!"
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_method.real_self = self
        self.kk = [":D"]
c = MyClass()
print(c)
c.some_method()
print(c.some_method)
```

Output:

```
I'm an instance of MyClass!
method is doing something... Here is an attrbute... [':D']
This is some_method You Dope! :P
```

---

Add the following somewhere above the class (perhaps a separate file) to create the annotation:

```
def toStr(str):
    def decorator(f):
        class _temp:
            def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                return f(self.real_self, *args, **kwargs)
            def __str__(self):
                return str%f.__name__
        return _temp()
    return decorator
```

---

Note that `self.some_method.real_self = self` is needed in `__init__` to ensure that the right `self` gets passed to the wrapped method.

Comment: In `f(self, *args, **kwargs)` you're actually passing `_temp`'s instance to `f`.

Comment: This is definitely looking good.  I like the decorator definition being in another file.  I can hide it in a library away from users.  Is there a way to have the decorator automatically extract the method name, rather than passing it manually to the decorator?

Comment: @JS. Yes, I have modified it to use the method's `__name__` to generate the string.

Comment: This implementation doesn't work. The method receives the wrong value for `self`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I have modified `_temp` to store the correct `self` and use that when calling `f`.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this same problem and I wasn't happy with either of the solutions here.  Martijn's solution using descriptors is the right approach, but it is not as elegant as a solution that provides a decorator (and some of the choices of argument names as well as the structure of his solution is unnecessarily confusing).  Navin's solution is not a good approach as it requires manually setting "real_self"; this is precisely the purpose of descriptors.  Here I wanted to override __repr__ instead of __str__, but that's just a detail, the solution is the same.

Here is my decorator which returns a descriptor solution:

```
from functools import update_wrapper

# the usual outer function to allow the decorator to accept an argument
def custom_repr(repr_text):
    # the decorator itself
    def method_decorator(method):

        # Wrap the method in our own descriptor.
        class CustomReprDescriptor(object):

            def __get__(self, instance, owner):
                # Return our wrapped method when we call instance.method
                # This class encapsulates the method
                class MethodWrapper(object):
                    # Callable with custom __repr__ method
                    # Capture the instance and owner (type) from the __get__ call
                    def __init__(self):
                        self.im_self = instance
                        self.im_class = owner
                        self.im_func = method

                    # Call the wrapped method using the captured instance
                    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                        return self.im_func(self.im_self, *args, **kwargs)

                    # Capture the custom __repr__ text from the decorator call
                    def __repr__(self):
                        return repr_text
                # The call to __get__ returns our wrapped method with custom __repr__
                return update_wrapper(MethodWrapper(), method)
        # The decorator returns our custom descriptor
        return CustomReprDescriptor()
    return method_decorator

class TestClass(object):

    @custom_repr("Test of custom repr.")
    def re_repr_method(self):
        print "Called re-repred method."

tc = TestClass
tc.re_repr_method()
print "rc.re_repr_method.__name__ = " + tc.re_repr_method.__name__
print repr(tc.re_repr_method)
```

Output:

```
Called re-repred method.
rc.re_repr_method.__name__ = re_repr_method
Test of custom repr.
```

The key to understanding all of this is that when you write a method in a class declaration in python, you are not doing anything special - merely defining a function in the namespace of that class.  However, then some syntactic sugar kicks in (or at least I believe this happens): Python then wraps that method inside a descriptor, which handles calling that function with the instance of the class as the self argument.  So, all we need to do is take this step ourselves; rather than let Python convert our class-level function into a method, just wrap it ourselves in a descriptor whose __get__ method returns a callable whose __call__ method calls the function we want as our method, but which has a __repr__ method of our choosing.